# Tight Junctions in Cell Types

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane

I took a quiz today on cell structure basics, which included cell junction types. I disagree with the "correct answer" according to the teacher.

Here is the question:

```
Which cell type would have the most tight junctions?

a) Pancrease cells
b) Ovarian cells
c) Epithelial cells (in the intestine)
d) Muscle cells (skeletal)
```

According to my teacher, muscle cells is the correct answer.

I argued that the answer should be epithelial cells, as muscles cells (according to the text) primarily use desmosomes for cell-to-cell adhesion, while epithelial cells rely on tight junctions primarily.

I searched it up quickly on Google, and from what I have found, epithelial cells is the correct answer.

Is my teacher incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tight junctions are very specifically a structure found in epithelial cells, so your teacher is incorrect. Tight junctions are what allow epithelial cells to form a selective barrier between compartments. Fibroblasts can be induced to form tight junctions under certain experimental conditions, but I'm not aware of any case where a skeletal muscle cell expresses a tight junction. Regardless, it would *not* be normal physiology.

You can read more about tight junctions [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26857/), in the online Albert's Molecular Biology of the Cell. This figure from that Chapter illustrates the barrier function.

[image]

If you want to get into more of the details re: what we know about the various proteins involved in creating and regulating tight junctions, [this is a good review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4254347/).

One small correction to your reasoning, though, I wouldn't say the primary purpose of tight junctions is cell-to-cell adhesion, per se, it's selective permeability. These junctions may help the cells to hold together, but the tissues can resist shear stress in knock-out models. A knockout model without a necessary tight junction protein, however, will not maintain selective permeability.